# "letting oneself be summoned out of"

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature

> In Heidegger's view, man has a tendency to lose himself in his world and "forget" his mortality, and by extension that of his world. He falls in with the crowd (the "they"), engages in idle chatter, lets himself be absorbed by average everydayness all in order to avoid the fundamental question of his existence and its responsibility. We are inauthentic creatures: […] Heidegger claims, a confrontation with our finitude, an "authentic being-toward-death." It would mean heeding the call of conscience, to exhibit "care" toward the manifestation of Being. And above all, it would demand a new “resoluteness”, which signifies “**letting oneself be summoned out of one's lostness in the ‘they.’**”

Could you please help me with understanding the bold passage from [the above excerpt](http://www.driftline.org/cgi-bin/archive/archive_msg.cgi?file=spoon-archives/heidegger.archive/heidegger_1999/heidegger.9911&msgnum=82&start=9530&end=10148). It comes from Heidegger's *Being and Time*. (I am especially confused by the phrase "to be summoned out of".) Does it mean that the man to live the authentic life should gather one's strength and experience his/her lostness outside of the crowd, outside of the other people?

Comment: To understand it we'd need more context. If the whole book is like that then we'd probably need *lots* of context.

Comment: I edited the question to include a link to the text that contains the passage that may be found on Google Books.

Comment: Heidegger wrote in German (this is from *Sein und Zeit*) and this sounds like a much-to-literal translation. Of course, he probably wrote in deutcher Philosophensprache, which may mean that by far the safest way to translate it is literally.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman It doesn't look like an exact quote...

Comment: @curiousdannii: it was originally written in German. Of course it's not an exact quote. It's probably an exact quote from one translation, but there may be other translations.

Comment: @PeterShor Just pointing out that Benjamin's link wasn't to the same translation, so it shouldn't really be in the question

Comment: Which is **exactly** why the translation should be linked (or at least referenced) so the particular edition can be looked at, and compared to others.

Comment: This passage may have been retranslated by the guy who quoted it, and might not be found in any translation of *Being and Time*.

Comment: "Summoned of" is indeed nonsensical.  "Summoned out of" is OK.

Comment: And what does "summoned out of" mean? I am not able to find the meaning of this (phrasal?) verb.

Comment: @curiousdannii: I've added a link to the actual source. I think to understand exactly what's meant by the highlighted text, one would need to read much of the preceding context. I get the impression "resoluteness" (in scare quotes in the original) might not be a very good translation of whatever German word Heidegger *might* have used (though it's not certain to me that part actually reflects anything at all from the original). Whatever, the cited text is barely "English" at all, so exactly what it means is essentially ***a matter of opinion.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers found a better reference which contains the full text, if one reads the preceding passage the citation makes more sense.

Comment: Just this one short excerpt includes no less than *six* terms enclosed in scare quotes, which suggests that English is hopelessly inadequate for talking about such matters, ***and/or*** the subject matter is so abstruse we're probably wasting our time attempting to paraphrase the text so it will be easily understood by someone who's not even a native speaker. Personally, I find the juxtaposition of *resoluteness* (holding on) and *letting oneself be summoned* (giving in) so jarring that I would seek a better translation if it mattered to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not attempting to decipher the entire piece--

"Summoned out of one's lostness" makes sense, as a metaphor of sorts.  (Though it certainly is not any sort if idiom.)  In this sense, "summoned" basically means getting the individual's attention, as if awakening from sleep or a trance or whatever.  "Lostness" here could mean either simple "aimlessness", or something akin to depression, or, more likely, a loss of personal direction due to being distracted by external forces (such as "the crowd" ==> the "they").

So "letting oneself be summoned out of one's lostness in the ‘they’" means exercising a "resoluteness" such that one consciously avoids the external distractions of "they" and instead focuses the mind on whatever it is that Heidegger thinks is so gol danged important here.

Answer (score -1):

It refers to allowing oneself to be summoned out of an *inauthentic existence*, one driven by others' perceptions, or rather one's perception of others' perceptions of oneself, but a more complete explanation may be found on page 29 of [*Adorno and Heidegger: Philosophical Questions*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wGGfAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=letting%20oneself%20be%20summoned%20of%20one%27s%20lostnes%20in%20the%20%22they%22&source=bl&ots=1Zp-wrApPh&sig=Dkp_kVpnagmTVOEpLCZHa5jFbHo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir9qTd-aHKAhWLsh4KHVUwBX0Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=letting%20oneself%20be%20summoned%20of%20one's%20lostnes%20in%20the%20%22they%22&f=false).  It fully explains what it is believed that Heidegger meant.

Comment: Please summarise the main points. This is a link-only answer.

Comment: @Andrew Leach : Main point now summarised.